# Dictionary from text file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this text file:

```
English 
hello bye 
italian 
ciao hola
spanish
hola chao
```

I want to create a dictionary from each 2 consecutive lines:

```
{
    'English': 'hello bye',
    'italian': 'ciao hola',
    'spanish': 'hola chao',
}
```

Here's my code:

```
d= {}
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    l = f.readlines()
    for line in l:
        (key,val) = line.split()
        d[key]=val
```

I get the error:

> too many values to unpack error

Comment: the text file has English in the first line and the word in second line and so on

Comment: Are the keys always written at the odd lines, while the words are written at even lines?

Comment: Do you need comma between `'hello'` and `'bye'`? If not, please correct it.

Comment: If you control this input file, I would suggest an alternative format. For example `{"phrase":"hello world", "translations": [{"spanish": "..."}, {"italian":"..."}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
d = {}
prev_key = None
for line in l:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        prev_key = line
    else:
        d[prev_key] = line
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this approach:

```
d = {}
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    l = f.readlines()
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        d[l[i].replace("\n","")] = l[i+1].replace("\n","")
        i += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you are reading all lines in the file in one go using `f.readlines()` and then you are splitting each line. The problem is that not each line is giving you a list with two elements, so `key, val = line.split()` gives you a `values to unpack`, since you are trying to assign a single element list to two items. e.g `a,b = [2]` which will result in this error like so.

```
In [66]: a,b = [2]                                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-f9f79b7d1d3c> in <module>
----> 1 a,b = [2]

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

To avoid it, we just iterate through the lines we read, and every even element is a key and every odd element is a value in the dictionary.

```
dct = {}
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    l = f.readlines()
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(l):
        #Even element is key, Odd element is value
        key = l[idx].strip()
        value = l[idx+1].strip()
        dct[key] = value
        idx+=2
#{'English': 'hello bye', 'italian': 'ciao hola', 'spanish': 'hola chao'}
```

Or a more terse solution using dict-comprehension is

```
l = []
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    l = f.readlines()

#This will be a list of tuples, with the first element of tuple being the key #and second value being the value
#Keys are obtained by slicing all even indexes, and values by slicing all odd indexes
key_value_tups = zip(l[::2], l[1::2])
#[('English \n', 'hello bye \n'), ('italian \n', 'ciao hola\n'), ('spanish\n', 'hola chao\n')]

#Iterate through the tuples and create the dict via dict-comprehension
dct = {key.strip() : value.strip() for key, value in key_value_tups}

print(dct)
#{'English': 'hello bye', 'italian': 'ciao hola', 'spanish': 'hola chao'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line :

```py
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

dict( zip( lines[::2], lines[1::2] ) )
```

- `lines[::2]` will give you all the elements of `lines` that have an even index
- `lines[1::2]` will give you all the elements of `lines` that have an odd index
  `zip` will create an iterator `(list1 elem, list2 elem)` from the two lists
- `dict` will take each tuple `(key, value)` from the iterator as a dictionary item and create a dictionary

That one line is the equivalent of :

```py
keys = []
values = []
for index, elem in enumerate(lines):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        keys += [elem]
    else:
        values += [elem]

d = {}
for key, val in zip(keys, values):
    d[key] = val
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary-comprehension using `zip()`:

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    l = f.readlines()
    d = {x: y for x, y in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])}
```